# NVMe S.M.A.R.T. data retrieval

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi, hard-drive

I have developed a program which is able to retrieve the smart data for SATA devices with the help of WMI like so:
`Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'Root\WMI' -Class 'MSStorageDriver_ATAPISMartData' | Select -ExpandProperty Vendorspecific` however, it is not able to get the NVMe's one. Any of you know some way to retrieve it? (Even if it is not a Powershell cmdlet)

Apparently Microsoft docs have addressed the issue:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/working-with-nvme-devices
however, I am unable to execute the code if anyone manages to solve it and send me source code it would be appreciated

Comment: Does your NVMe device actually return any SMART under say Ubuntu LiveDVD? If not, you can't. Otherwise you need the proper class, as NVMe is definitely NOT ATAPI.

Comment: It does return S.M.A.R.T. data through smartmontools, crystaldisk etc.. 
My disc model is: Intel SSDPEDMW012T4 1.2TB

Comment: According to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/af01ce5d-b2a6-4442-b229-6bb32033c755/using-wmi-to-get-smart-status-of-a-hard-disk?forum=vbgeneral), you need to gather the items of `MSStorageDriver_FailurePredictData` class from `root\wmi` namespace. Can't yet verify this as I don't have a physical Windows host around that I am admin, byt please do try.

Comment: It does not pick up the NVMe as a drive and shows no information about it. I have tried it on multiple machines and the only drives that do not display information are the NVMes so I guess there is some other way of reading their SMART data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has published documentation on [Working with NVMe drives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/working-with-nvme-devices). The way you retrieve S.M.A.R.T. data from NVMe in C++ is the following:

my definition for the wszDrive is: `#define  wszDrive L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive1"`

You can specify the number of the drive starting from 0 (for the first drive)

```
HANDLE hDevice = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;  // handle to the drive to be examined 

    hDevice = CreateFileW((LPWSTR)wszDrive,          // drive to open
        0,                // no access to the drive
        FILE_SHARE_READ | // share mode
        FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL,             // default security attributes
        OPEN_EXISTING,    // disposition
        FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,                // file attributes
        NULL);            // do not copy file attributes

    if (hDevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)    // cannot open the drive
    {
        return (FALSE);
    }

    BOOL    result;
    PVOID   buffer = NULL;
    ULONG   bufferLength = 0;
    ULONG   returnedLength = 0;

    PSTORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY query = NULL;
    PSTORAGE_PROTOCOL_SPECIFIC_DATA protocolData = NULL;
    PSTORAGE_PROTOCOL_DATA_DESCRIPTOR protocolDataDescr = NULL;

    //
    // Allocate buffer for use.
    //
    bufferLength = FIELD_OFFSET(STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY, AdditionalParameters) + sizeof(STORAGE_PROTOCOL_SPECIFIC_DATA) + NVME_MAX_LOG_SIZE;
    buffer = malloc(bufferLength);

    if (buffer == NULL) {
        _tprintf(_T("DeviceNVMeQueryProtocolDataTest: allocate buffer failed, exit.\n"));
        goto exit;
    }

    //
    // Initialize query data structure to get Identify Controller Data.
    //
        ZeroMemory(buffer, bufferLength);

    query = (PSTORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY)buffer;
    protocolDataDescr = (PSTORAGE_PROTOCOL_DATA_DESCRIPTOR)buffer;
    protocolData = (PSTORAGE_PROTOCOL_SPECIFIC_DATA)query->AdditionalParameters;

    query->PropertyId = StorageDeviceProtocolSpecificProperty;
    query->QueryType = PropertyStandardQuery;

    protocolData->ProtocolType = ProtocolTypeNvme;
    protocolData->DataType = NVMeDataTypeLogPage;
    protocolData->ProtocolDataRequestValue = NVME_LOG_PAGE_HEALTH_INFO;
    protocolData->ProtocolDataRequestSubValue = 0;  // This will be passed as the lower 32 bit of log page offset if controller supports extended data for the Get Log Page.
    protocolData->ProtocolDataRequestSubValue2 = 0; // This will be passed as the higher 32 bit of log page offset if controller supports extended data for the Get Log Page.
    protocolData->ProtocolDataRequestSubValue3 = 0; // This will be passed as Log Specific Identifier in CDW11.

    protocolData->ProtocolDataOffset = sizeof(STORAGE_PROTOCOL_SPECIFIC_DATA);
    protocolData->ProtocolDataLength = sizeof(NVME_HEALTH_INFO_LOG);

    //  
    // Send request down.  
    //  
    result = DeviceIoControl(hDevice,
        IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY,
        buffer,
        bufferLength,
        buffer,
        bufferLength,
        &returnedLength,
        NULL
    );

    if (!result || (returnedLength == 0)) {
        _tprintf(_T("DeviceNVMeQueryProtocolDataTest: SMART/Health Information Log failed. Error Code %d.\n"), GetLastError());
        goto exit;
    }

        //
        // Validate the returned data.
        //
        if ((protocolDataDescr->Version != sizeof(STORAGE_PROTOCOL_DATA_DESCRIPTOR)) ||
            (protocolDataDescr->Size != sizeof(STORAGE_PROTOCOL_DATA_DESCRIPTOR))) {
            _tprintf(_T("DeviceNVMeQueryProtocolDataTest: SMART/Health Information Log - data descriptor header not valid.\n"));
            return 0;
        }

    protocolData = &protocolDataDescr->ProtocolSpecificData;

    if ((protocolData->ProtocolDataOffset < sizeof(STORAGE_PROTOCOL_SPECIFIC_DATA)) ||
        (protocolData->ProtocolDataLength < sizeof(NVME_HEALTH_INFO_LOG))) {
        _tprintf(_T("DeviceNVMeQueryProtocolDataTest: SMART/Health Information Log - ProtocolData Offset/Length not valid.\n"));
        goto exit;
    }

        //
        // SMART/Health Information Log Data 
        //
    {
        PNVME_HEALTH_INFO_LOG smartInfo = (PNVME_HEALTH_INFO_LOG)((PCHAR)protocolData + protocolData->ProtocolDataOffset);

// print the S.M.A.R.T. data which you need

        _tprintf(_T("DeviceNVMeQueryProtocolDataTest: SMART/Health Information Log Data - Temperature %d.\n"), ((ULONG)smartInfo->Temperature[1] << 8 | smartInfo->Temperature[0]) - 273);
        _tprintf(_T("DeviceNVMeQueryProtocolDataTest: SMART/Health Information Log Data - Available Spares: %d.\n"), ((ULONG)smartInfo->AvailableSpare));

        _tprintf(_T("DeviceNVMeQueryProtocolDataTest: ***SMART/Health Information Log succeeded***.\n"));
    }
    exit:
```

Comment: I wonder if this could be added to a powershell script with c# code and add-type.

Comment: Would be great if someone extended Krugertech.IO.Smart (public repo) with this code and C# hooks.